# Add a "View all" button on WooCommerce product archives pages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add view all button on my woo-commerce product page after pagination.after clicking the view all button all product will be open.

Comment: Can you please let me know website URL or with screenshot where exactly you want to display this button so I can clearly understand and will help you.

Comment: https://divanodesignsus.com/product-category/living/

Comment: after pagination i want to add view all please help me out

Comment: My code is working for you or not??? Please let me know.

Comment: no sir your code is not working but i try another way to do this add some function on function.php now it's working

Comment: i have one another question 
i want an option while uploading any product image in woo-commerce. option are vertical or landscape.when i select the landscape mode image will display in landscape mode in front end.i already search on google but not get any answer

Answer (score 2):

I will offer you a different approach, without the need to actually edit the template files. All you need to do is add those two action hooks to your `function.php` file (make sure you are using a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)):

```
/**
 * This will add a 'Show All' link after the pagination on the shop pages.
 * It will be hidden once it is activated.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'wpse333192_add_showall', 40 );

function wpse333192_add_showall() {

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['showall'] ) ) {
        global $wp;

        echo sprintf(
            "<a href='%s'>%s</a>",
            home_url( add_query_arg( array_merge( $_GET, [ 'showall' => 1 ] ), $wp->request ) ),
            __( 'Show All', 'text-domain' )
        );
    }

}

/**
 * This will alter the main product query if 'showall' is activated
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse333192_alter_query_showall' );

function wpse333192_alter_query_showall( $query ) {

    /**
     * Alter the query only if it is:
     * 1. The main query
     * 2. Post type is product
     * 3. $_GET['showall'] is set
     * 4. $_GET['showall'] equals 1
     */
    if ( $query->is_main_query()
         && $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'product'
         && isset( $_GET['showall'] )
         && $_GET['showall'] == 1
    ) {
        // Load the 'first' page
        $query->set( 'paged', 1 );

        // Set post per page to unlimited
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', - 1 );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it's working perfectly on my website

Comment: I am really glad to hear that. If you like an answer, you should give it the upvote. And don't forget to mark the best answer that solves your problem as well. :)

Comment: i have another question can you help me out

Comment: Yes, but if it is not completely related to this one, you should start another thread by crrating a new question.

Comment: i already create new question please check .

Answer (score 0):

> **Put below code after** this action `<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); ?>` in `archive-product.php` file.
>
> **For Category Products Page**

```
<?php
$cat_data = get_queried_object();
$cat_id = $cat_data->term_id;
if(is_product_category()  && !isset($_GET['showall'])){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $cat_id, 'product_cat' ) . "?showall=1"; ?>">Show all</a>
<?php } ?>
```

> **For Shop Page**

```
<?php if(is_shop() && !isset($_GET['showall'])){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) . "?showall=1"; ?>">Show all</a>
<?php } ?>
```

---

> Just add the conditional check to your `functions.php` file

```
if(isset( $_GET['showall']) ){ 
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return -1;' ) ); 
} else {
    $default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return '.$default_posts_per_page.';' ) );
}
```

Comment: @saurabh-srivastava please add code Like this screenshot http://prntscr.com/n6avb7

Comment: @saurabh-srivastava I have tested code and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

create_function() is deprecated. You should use below code to get the desired result.

```
  add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'show_all' ); 
function show_all($cols){
    if(isset( $_GET['showall']) ){ 
    
    return $cols = -1;
} else {
    $default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    return $default_posts_per_page;
}
}
```